# Pandas: How to create a new column which contains number of each weekday inside month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

There is a Pandas Dataframe with datetime column as index.

```
time                    open     high      low    close  weekday                                        
2000-05-30 17:00:00  0.93020  0.93050  0.92970  0.92970        1
2000-05-30 18:00:00  0.92980  0.93000  0.92960  0.92960        1
2000-05-30 19:00:00  0.92970  0.93050  0.92930  0.93050        1
```

I created new column 'weekday' as

```
df['weekday'] = df.index.dayofweek
```

How to create a new column which contains number of each weekday inside each month?
i.e 2000-05-01 is 1-st monday in May , 2000-05-08 is 2-nd May , etc...

Comment: df.index.day is the day of month (0 - 31)
df.index.weekday is wheether your day is M-F or S-U (0 or 1)
df.index.dayofweek is numbering days from Monday (0) to Sunday (6)

Your question is asking for both 'weekday' and 'day of month'

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to divide the day number by 7.
If the remainder of the division is greater than 0, then 1 must be added to the result of the division.
For example, 02/09/2021. Divide 9 by 7. The remainder of the division is not 0. The result of division is 1. Add 1. So 02/09/2020 is the second Tuesday in February.

Answer (score 0):

If your time column is a datetime dtype then

```
df['weekday'] = df['time'].dt.day_of_week
```

If not, then do this first

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```